# Assertion Failed Auto_Ptr Not Deferencable

Tags: c++

I'm using std::auto_ptr in C++ and below is my code,

```
void fSample(std::auto_ptr<CFoo> pParam)
{
    CFoo* pFoo = pParam.release();
    fTodo(pFoo);
}
```

The code above gives me **`Assertion failed: auto_ptr not derefencable`** runtime error.

Please advise.

Thanks!

Comment: Give up with auto_ptr. Use std::unique_ptr or std::shared_ptr

Comment: Can't give up auto_ptr, legacy codes :(

Comment: Do something about your accept-rate, please.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the auto_ptr by reference. Also, auto_ptr is deprecated. Use unique_ptr.

```
void fSample(std::auto_ptr<CFoo> &pParam) // <= Note the ampersand
{
    CFoo* pFoo = pParam.release();
    fTodo(pFoo);
}
```